# How would I use sed or awk to extract certain lines in a file

Tags: files, sed, awk, search

If I wanted to search for all lines in a file that start with a date, such as "May 1", how would I do that with sed or awk? I need to extract this data and either send to screen or a file. Thanks.

Comment: Is May the only month, or are you looking for any month followed by a date?

Comment: In this example I need every line that begins with "May 1", but it could be other months.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To extract lines that start with `May 1`:

```
grep "^May 1\b" file
```

Or:

```
sed -n '/^May 1\>/p' file
```

Or:

```
awk '/^May 1\>/' file
```

The above two assume a tool, such as the GNU awk or sed, that supports `\>` as a word boundary regex. The purpose of the word boundary is to prevent the regex from matching, for example, `May 10`.

#### More

If you are looking for any day in May:

```
grep -E "^May [[:digit:]]{1,2}\b" file
```

If you are looking for any day of any month:

```
grep -E "^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) [[:digit:]]{1,2}\b" file
```

Comment: Probably safer to use an anchor: `/^May [0-9]{1,2}/`

Comment: Yes yes, this would be the easiest route. awk or sed would need some regex statements.

Comment: @jasonwryan Yes, some anchoring is good.  I was reading it that he wanted `May 1` but I see that you have asked for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf %s\\n 'Apr 30 aaa' \
             'May 1 bbb' \
             'Feb 29 ccc' \
             'Feb 30 ddd' |

sed -n '/^\(Apr\|Jun\|Sep\|Nov\) \([1-9]\|[12][0-9]\|30\)\>/p
        /^\(Jan\|Mar\|Jul\|Aug\|May\|Oct\|Dec\) \([1-9]\|[12][0-9]\|3[01]\)\>/p
        /^\(Feb\) \([1-9]\|[12][0-9]\)\>/p'
```

Output:

```
Apr 30 aaa
May 1 bbb
Feb 29 ccc
```